# (java) i want to change to "getSelectedValuesList()” from "getMinSelectionIndex();” from List in this code

Tags: java, list, jlist, jfilechooser, listselectionlistener

#### Purpose

I am customizing an App for personal use. This App can make many midi files in Java.

i want to change to  "getSelectedValuesList()” from "getMinSelectionIndex();” in this code

Because I want to choose and SAVE many files in one time  from list.
I already could select many files in one time.

(I already changed below)

```
public interface ListSelectionModel
{
int MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION = 2;
}
```

#### Problems

- I can’t save many files in one time from list.

(Error message)

> getSelectedValuesList() is not defined in ListSelectionModel

#### My idea

I changed a chord like this. But it is error.

.getMinSelectionIndex();

=> .getSelectedValuesList();

#### Source cord

(Original cord)

```
  /**
 * To send a selected table model, that is MIDI sequence. 
 * @return => selected MIDI sequence table model. (If we don’t choose, it is null)
 */
public SequenceTrackListTableModel getSelectedSequenceModel() {
    if( sequenceListSelectionModel.isSelectionEmpty() ) return null;
    int selectedIndex = sequenceListSelectionModel.getMinSelectionIndex();
    if( selectedIndex >= sequenceList.size() ) return null;
    return sequenceList.get(selectedIndex);
}
```

(My Idea)

```
  /**
 * To send a selected table model, that is MIDI sequence. 
 * @return => selected MIDI sequence table model. (If we don’t choose, it is null)
 */
public SequenceTrackListTableModel getSelectedSequenceModel() {
    if( sequenceListSelectionModel.isSelectionEmpty() ) return null;
    int selectedIndex = sequenceListSelectionModel.getSelectedValuesList();
    if( selectedIndex >= sequenceList.size() ) return null;
    return sequenceList.get(selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: do you have access to  interface called ListSelectionModel and its implementations ?

Comment: yes. I can see ListSelectionModel.class. But i can't edit it.

Comment: I think ListSelectionModel.class from Oracle company is so old and simple...

Comment: I expect its better to use Class JList<E> instead of  ListSelectionModel. that is after JDK 1.7. but I am confused...

Comment: how are you creating the object sequenceListSelectionModel in your code and also if my understanding is correct you just need to rename the method name ?

Comment: `public ListSelectionModel sequenceListSelectionModel = new DefaultListSelectionModel() {
  {
   setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
  }
 };`

Comment: sequenceListSelectionModel is written like this.
I tried to change the method name, to .getSelectedValuesList(); from .getMinSelectionIndex();.
But its error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyListSelectionModel extends DefaultListSelectionModel{
   public returntypeoftheExistinggetMinSelectionIndex getSelectedValuesList(){
     return getMinSelectionIndex();
   }
}
```

And while creating the sequenceListSelectionModel object use the new class like

```
public ListSelectionModel sequenceListSelectionModel = new MyListSelectionModel ()
```

Answer (score 0):

hummm...
I tried to write like this.
I think your explain means like this. Now there is no error message, but i could't save files at the same time.

Im wondering about Type of "returnTypeOfTheExisting" and "getSelectedValuesList()".
Because these contains MIDI sequence file. these are not "Int"....
I expect I need to change it.

```
package javax.swing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyListSelectionModel extends DefaultListSelectionModel {
        public int returnTypeOfTheExisting = getMinSelectionIndex();

    int getSelectedValuesList() {
         return getMinSelectionIndex();
       };
    }
```

--

```
public ListSelectionModel sequenceListSelectionModel = new MyListSelectionModel();
```

Comment: getMinSelectionIndex(); means single file now.
I want to select many or all MIDI files. so I need to change it maybe...

Answer (score 0):

I need to use ArrayList?

```
public class MyListSelectionModel extends DefaultListSelectionModel {
public ArrayList<String> returnTypeOfTheExisting = getSelectedValuesList();

ArrayList<String> getSelectedValuesList() {
    ArrayList<String> testSelect = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListModel<String> starsCohort = null;
    JList<String> starsList = new JList<String>(starsCohort);
    testSelect.addAll(starsList.getSelectedValuesList());
    return (testSelect);
};
```

}

I am so sorry. maybe i don't good knowledge about java.

Comment: yes you need to use the same return type as getSelectedValuesList if its ArrayList<String> then use that one only